# Скрипт для подсчету нажатий на ссылку

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Посоветуйте какой-нибудь скрипт для подсчету нажатий на ссылку (php).

Comment: с бд обязательно!

Comment: это как бы надо для скачивания файлов с сайта

Comment: У вас САР (букс)? это что?

Comment: если что сайт самописный

Comment: Я ссылку на урок в своём ответе вам выложил. САР - это система активной рекламы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте сами. Просто на каждую ссылку повесьте обработчик и все желаемые сайты будут ссылаться на него `http://site1.ru/click.php?href=id_href`, `id_href` - идентификатор ссылки. В БД создать таблицу из столбцов `id, href, clicks`.
В обработчике `click.php` обновляйте кол-во кликов и переадресуйте на полученную по `id_href` ссылку. Более круто можно сделать через ajax, тогда ссылки не будут изменятся, но это уже другая технология. У вас САР (букс)?

[Скрипт подсчета кликов](http://www.comprog.ru/PHP/article_2195.htm)
Вот подробный урок о том, как это сделать.

Comment: Пробовал, но не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

[и еще](http://subcoder.ru/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5/) 
готовый